# Why does mathematica give wrong answer for the derivative?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, radix, exponential, derivative

I am trying to find the derivative of

> 3<sup>x</sup>

The derivative should be

> ln (3) 3<sup>x</sup>

However, the Mathematica gives me the answer as

> Log[3] 3<sup>x</sup>

I am using Mathematica 11.2 Student Edition. Can somebody help me why this is happening?

Comment: It's just a slightly different notation for the same thing, no ?

Comment: mathematica is not intended for pretty typesetting. You will make yourself crazy if you sweat over how things look.  That said try mathematica.stackexchange.com maybe there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The default base for [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log.html) in Mathematica is *e*, so `Log[3]` is the natural log of 3, or ln(3). It means the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Bill the Lizard. However, what if I want the answer in Ln (3) rather than Log (3). Is there a way?

Comment: @RajeshRajchal Sorry, I don't know of a way.

Comment: @RajeshRajchal you could do `D[3^x,x]/.Log->Ln`. This is however bad practice as Mathemtica does not know what `Ln` is and cannot manipulate it in further evaluations. Hence, just stick to the `Log` notation.